# How to hide (not destroy) a BrowserView in Electron

Tags: electron

I'm working in **Electron 5.0.3** and I want to hide a **BrowserView** such that the BrowserView doesn't need to be re created. I don't have any preference on how this should be achieved. Any solution (JS, CSS, etc.) would suffice.

I've looked through the [BrowserView documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view) and there is nothing in here that i see that could help, and moving the BrowserView to somewhere off screen isn't exactly ideal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**First Solution (optimal):**

```
browserWindow.addBrowserView(browserView)
browserWindow.removeBrowserView(browserView)
```

[addBrowserView()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winaddbrowserviewbrowserview-experimental) &
[removeBrowserView()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winremovebrowserviewbrowserview-experimental). Removing the browser view is the same as hiding, it will not make the browserView re-render.

**Secondary solution (not optimal):**

```
// not optimal if you call more than once because it will constantly add more CSS
browserView.webContents.insertCSS('html{display: block}')
browserView.webContents.insertCSS('html{display: none}')
```

[insertCSS()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsinsertcsscss)

Comment: When I do this, it does re-render the `BrowserView` State is lost everytime.

Comment: @J.Hesters both of these solutions work across all versions of electron that the functions exist in. I'm using the top solution in an App and it's doing as stated. Not quite sure why it doesn't work for you :/

Comment: Thank you. I found it out! I was reloading the url each time. Once I got rid of that, everything worked 

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old but I ran into a problem with this solution and have an alternative.

There are scenarios where removing the `BrowserView` from the `BrowserWindow` can have some unintended consequences. I have found that if you are using a `BrowserView` to host external content that while removing and setting seems to preserve the content, you may lose some ability to interact with it via code (e.g. via `view.webContents.executeJavaScript()`) or in some circumstances UI controls that call an async event sometimes stop working altogether.

If all you want to do is hide the `BrowserView`, setting the bounds to 0 works really well:

```
  view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 })
```

Then restore it using the host `BrowserWindow` dimensions:

```
  let wb = win.getBounds()
  view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: wb.width, height: wb.height })
```

Side note: there is a difference between `setBrowserView()` and `addBrowserView()`. The former will remove all other `BrowserViews` from the `BrowserWindow` (meaning there is no need to explicitly remove a view if you are also setting it and that if you are using add you need to manage your views.)